# Display selection of index in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to solve the following challenge all day without any luck.

When going through forum posts I came across jQuery and AJAX which are both new concepts to me and which I'd rather skip for now, if possible.

I've got a partial, "navbar-left", which shows a list of all bank accounts in my model Account.
When the user clicks on one of the items in the list, all transactions of that account should be shown in the same page at the right. The partial below links to a new page which is not how I'd like it.

The navbar-partial:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <% @accounts.each do |account| %>
    <li role="presentation"><%= link_to account.account_holder, account_mutations_path(account.id) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Any tips on how to get this fixed is much appreciated!

[The page with the navbar at the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ae4.png)

[The mutations in a separate page instead of a partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY4s5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you're sending viewers to a new page, or dynamically loading content within their current page.

If the latter, then the only solution is AJAX.

Luckily, Ruby on Rails makes transitioning from one to the other very easy.

Here is a gist of how it works:

```
<%= link_to account.account_holder, account_mutations_path(account.id), remote: true %>
```

This was pointing back to some page previously (e.g. `action.html.erb`).

Because of `remote: true`, it's going to be sending JS directly to the browser instead of a new HTML page (e.g. `action.js.erb` in the same view folder and same action name).

Here we can control the behavior we want by rendering a partial using ERB and using JS to change the HTML content of some part of the page:

```
// action.js.erb
$('#some_element').html('<%= j render "partial" %>')
```

Which will insert the HTML of the partial directly into the JQuery that changes the content dynamically.

Where `j` is a shorthand for `escape_javascript`.

Without escaping, the Ruby output is interpreted as file output and newlines would break your JS.

Example JS output without escaping:

```
// Bad
$('#some_element').html('<span>Content</span>
<span>More Content</span>')
```

Example with escaping:

```
// Good
$('#some_element').html('<span>Content</span>\n<span>More Content</span>')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

https://launchschool.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails

There are more great examples online and even Railscasts.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks fbelanger for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Really AJAX is the best way to do this, and it's not as complicated as you might think.  But if you really want to skip AJAX then your best approach is probably to load ALL transactions for all accounts, in different div's and then show or hide them based on which is clicked.

For a rudimentary introduction to this look at javascript tabs... you click on a tab, the appropriate information is shown.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply without ajax.  The big difference would be - it's not the same page.  One page would be the `account#index` (as you have now), the other page is the `account#show` page.

For the show page, use a very similar view as the index page, the left side would include the partial with one of the account `li class="active"` to highlight the account you are currently on.  For the right side of the page, render the account mutations list items.